# Is it possible in WIX to force user to scroll all Eula to proceed further?

Tags: wix, eula

We have a WIX Eula box , We need to make sure that user read all the EULA contents before he says accept ?

Is there any way to keep accept check box or button disabled until user scrolls it down completely?

Any help will be really appreciable.

Comment: Scrolling =/= reading. All you achieve is making your product marginally more annoying to install than your competitors product that does not do this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported by Windows Installer, so it cannot be done in WiX.

It's supported only by some setup authoring tools which use an external installation UI. Their external UI can detect the scroll position and update buttons accordingly.

So for now it would be best to simply use the standard behavior.